# Moving the message ID to the parseInt()

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been struggling with it a bit and I can't think of anything. Namely, I need to get the `id` of the message (embed) sent by the bot and save it as a `parseInt()` variable. I have no idea how to do it, and my attempts so far ended in failure. Below is my code and console logs.

```
[code...]

let msgID = parseInt()

msg.channel.send(smnyEmbed).then(e => {
  console.log(e.id)

  msgID = e.id
})

console.log(msgID)
```

Logs:

```
NaN <- msgID
82243920***9184779 <- e.id
```

Comment: You are not passing anything to parseInt()

Comment: I forgot to add to my question -> `msgID = e.id`

Comment: Relevant: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting `NaN` from `msgID` is because you didn't pass the method anything to parse into an integer. To get the message ID as an integer, you can do

```js
var msgID;
msg.channel.send(smnyEmbed).then(e => {
  console.log(e.id);
  msgID = parseInt(e.id);
})

console.log(msgID)
```

Comment: I am getting an error `ReferenceError: msgID is not defined`

Comment: Try moving the definition outside of the `.then`. I have updated my answer to show this.

Comment: @SirArchibald changing the declaration doesn't really help. The main problem is that it's asynchronous code. `msgID = parseInt(e.id); will always run after `console.log(msgID)` See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Comment: Does the nodejs version matter because I get the `undefined` error ?

Comment: No, the node version shouldn't matter. As VLAZ said, the issue is that JavaScript is run asynchronously. To get around this you may be able to `await` the `msg.channel.send` but you will need to add the code to an `async` function.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is:

```
let msgID;

msg.channel.send(smnyEmbed).then(e => {
  console.log(e.id);
  msgID = parseInt(e.id);
}).then(
    console.log(msgID);
);
```

Comment: I didn't notice that it's asynchronous function. now it should work.